# No .bash_profile in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos

I just did a clean install of OS X Lion and I see that now I have no .bash_profile file in my home directory.

Should I create this by hand? (I want to save in it some alias.)

Thank you.

PS : The only file that exist now that I could use is /etc/profile

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default this file does not exist on any version of OS X. And yes, it is up to you to create it manually:

`touch ~/.bash_profile`

Alternatively, you could use nano as well if you want to edit the file at the same time:

`nano ~/.bash_profile`

Do not monkey in `/etc` unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I just created the file and it worked fine after opening a new terminal window

Comment: You are welcome. If it solved your problem, please mark it as such to let others know if they ever reference this thread :)

Comment: Is there a reference in the OSX documentation for this?

Comment: @b.long I haven't see one. Not that I scoured it, but Apple doesn't tend to publicize UNIX config files. They tend to focus on making their OSes as less scary as possible. But since OS X is fully UNIX 3.0 compliant, anything that works in Linux works here. You can simply google "bash_profile" or "bashrc" (here's a good primer on the difference between the two: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).